# How acquire STS credentials for a mobile application to access secured S3 objects?

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam

I have deployed the backend service in AWS Fargate. I would like to acquire STS tokens in order to retrieve a set of secured S3 objects from the native mobile app. I use Terraform for creating infrastructure. I already have a Fargate task role `task-role` created. So for this particular usecase I created a new role `native-app-role` and assigned the `task-role` as a trusted relationship with permission to assume the `native-app-role`.

The following is the Terraform code:

```
# Fargate Role with trust relationship to ECS

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "fg_task_role_assume_role_policy_doc" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "sts:AssumeRole"
    ]

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [
        "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      ]
    }
  }
}


resource "aws_iam_role" "task_role" {
  name = "${var.application}-${var.namespace}-fargate-task-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.fg_task_role_assume_role_policy_doc.json

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.application}-${var.namespace}-fargate-task-role" # virtual-agent-alpha-fargate-task-role
  }
}


# Native app role with trust relationship to Fargate role
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "native_app_iam_policy_doc" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "sts:AssumeRole"
    ]

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type = "AWS"
      identifiers = [
        aws_iam_role.task_role.arn
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "virtual_agent_native_iam_role" {
  name = "${var.application}-${var.namespace}-native-application-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.native_app_iam_policy_doc.json

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.application}-native-${var.namespace}-role"
  }
}
```

Then I have use the following Kotlin code to obtain STS credentials:
Note: `roleArn` is the ARN of the `virtual_agent_native_iam_role`

```
fun getS3ReadOnlyTempCredentials(roleArn: String, bucket: String, objectKey: String, expiry: Expiry = Expiry(15, ChronoUnit.MINUTES)): AwsStsCredentials {
        val duration = Duration.of(expiry.duration, expiry.unit).toSeconds().toInt()
        val request = AssumeRoleRequest().apply {
            this.roleArn = roleArn
            roleSessionName = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            durationSeconds = duration
            policy = """
                {
                  "Id": "${UUID.randomUUID()}",
                  "Version": "2012-10-17",
                  "Statement": [
                    {
                      "Action": [
                        "s3:GetObject"
                      ],
                      "Effect": "Allow",
                      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::$bucket/$objectKey",
                      "Principal": {
                        "AWS": [ $roleArn ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        }

        return stsClient.assumeRole(request).credentials.let {
            AwsStsCredentials(it.accessKeyId, it.secretAccessKey, it.sessionToken, ZonedDateTime.now().plusSeconds(duration.toLong()) )
        }
```

When I execute this I get the following error:
`com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::913597729265:assumed-role/virtual-agent-alpha-fargate-task-role/c082fba5-3d13-4030-a457-9a18fb105efd is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: "arn:aws:iam::913597729265:role/virtual-agent-alpha-native-application-role" (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 573630b6-b02a-4185-ae5b-9360d05b4225)`

The above error says the `virtual-agent-alpha-fargate-task-role` does not have permission to assume the `virtual-native-role` but I have added the trust relationship via the `aussumeRole` attribute of `aws_iam_resource` of Terraform.

Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The mistake I made was not providing permission to the `task_role` to with `AssumeRole` permissions. Everything else stated in the question is done correctly. So in my terraform for `task_role` I had to attach a custom policy with the correct permissions.

Terraform code:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "virtual_agent_native_assume_role_policy_doc" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "virtual_agent_native_assume_role_policy" {
  name = "${var.application}-${var.namespace}-native-role-assume-role-policy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.virtual_agent_native_assume_role_policy_doc.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "task_role_virtual_agent_native_assume_role_policy_att" {
  role = aws_iam_role.task_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.virtual_agent_native_assume_role_policy.arn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your role creation is wrong. The policy that you created inside your code must be part of your `virtual_agent_native_iam_role` inside your terraform template.

You also don't need to assumeRole inside your code, your can configure your task to use a the execution role that you created in your terraform template. Check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html) for more information.

Comment: I can't add the policy in TF because i want the policies to be dynamic. Hence it's in code.

Comment: Ok, understood. Can I ask why are you creating two roles?

Comment: Maybe my understanding is wrong but in order for my ECS task to assume (task_role) it needs another role (native_role) with the correct permissions. So I created another role. Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: In my experience you don't need two roles in that scenario. It will work if you have two, but it is just an additional step that will not make any difference (considering that  you configured your roles correctly). But your session role will be the intersection of the permissions existent in your already created role (check my new answer for more details) and your AssumeRole request (aka SessionRole).

Answer (score 0):

I can try to help you with two alternatives, but to do that I need to confirm your use case. As I understood, you need to provide access for a specific user to read (during a defined interval of time) a specific s3 object. If this is the case here are my suggestions:

The first alternative would be to try to make your solution to work. But you'll need to test it because I don't have this scenario here: First I would remove the `virtual_agent_native_iam_role` and keep only the `task_role`. I would still need to call AssumeRole using the `task_role` and the specific `$bucket/$objectKey`. But there is something that is missing in your role configuration. As per [assume-role api documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html):

> The resulting session's permissions are the intersection of the role's identity-based policy and the session policies.

So to make it work your `task_role` policies should have permissions to allow more broad access to s3 and your method call would only restrict already existent policies. In that case I would attach a new policy to your `task_role` in your terraform template to allow the action `s3:GetObject` to all objects in the bucket (or if needed to all buckets in your account, dependent of your use case).

The AssumeRole call would be used to restrict the access of the temporary credentials to a specific `bucket/objectkey`.

But there is a second alternative that I believe would be much more simple. But you'll need to evaluate if it is applicable to your use case:

S3 allows you to create a temporary url for a specific object that would allow the user that have the url to get the object during a specific time interval. For that solution, you will also need to add a policy with permissions to `s3:GetObject` for `task_role`. But in that case you won't need to call the AssumeRole method in your code. You can just call the method to create the pre-signed url and send it back to your user. You can find more details about this alternative implementation using java-sdk [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-s3-presign.html).

With that scenario, the user will only have access to the selected object. Not the entire bucket.

Comment: I removed the new `virtual_agent_native_iam_role` and `AssumeRole`ed on `task_role`, now I get the following error:
`com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::913597729265:assumed-role/virtual-agent-alpha-fargate-task-role/68d70463-ebfc-4962-90cf-5a5a0fb99af7 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::913597729265:role/virtual-agent-alpha-fargate-task-role (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 69a39ccb-539e-402d-88b2-852b53f2c82a)`

Comment: The AssumeRole policy is needed in `task_role` to make it work. Using the code in the question as reference, you would need to remove the second half of the template snipet. Keep the data on top (AssumeRole for `task_role`) and the `aws_iam task_role`. In that scenario you wouldn't get this error... And you also would need to change your code to the `task_role` arn.